# Where does Spark Streaming run?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

As I understand, Spark can analyze streams with Spark Streaming. 
And Kafka can receive data from multiple sources.
What I don't understand is, if i have a Kafka cluster receiving data from multiple sources, will the data be send to a database with Spark Streaming running? Or is Spark Streaming running on a application server?

Comment: You can try to deploy the Spark cluster in the Kafka (Zookeeper) same cluster.
We have few environments in production one is Kafka + zookeeper ( in the same cluster) and spark standalone separate cluster main advantage  is  maintenance ( version upgrades,...)
But we also have in prod Kafka zookeeper and Apache Storm running on the same cluster( physical servers 100T ).
You can try to add Spark ( as standalone one jar) to your Kafka cluster ( with all necessary configuration port,...).

Comment: Also forgot to add if you are running on Kubernetes or Mesos then it doesn't matter which server you use, resources management will be done by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Spark Streaming, you need to set up a Spark cluster and you will submit you Spark Streaming job to the cluster. Thus, you will have to 2 cluster: Kafka + Spark (or actually 3, as you also need a Zookeeper cluster for Kafka).

Comment: so if i have a spark cluster, the spark job is running on an application server ? and is distributed to the spark cluster in mapreduce style ?